# Make a bouncing ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make my listview "bounce". To explain myself, I want the ListView to have the same behavior as the iOs List View object. On the top and on the bottom of the list, the user can go over the list by swiping his finger.

That behavior existed on Android 2.2 Samsung devices (Galaxy Tab GT1000 for instance).

On the most devices I tested, the list is now acting different on scrolling, it displays a blue line that gets brighter when you swipe your finger moreover.

I found the BounceListView like this one :

```
public class BounceListView extends ListView
{
    private static final int MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 200;

    private Context mContext;
    private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;

    public BounceListView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    public BounceListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    public BounceListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceListView();
    }

    private void initBounceListView()
    {
        //get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max overscroll distance
        //variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen size

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            final float density = metrics.density;

        mMaxYOverscrollDistance = (int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) 
    { 
        //This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming maxOverScrollY with our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance; 
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);  
    }

}
```

But the problem of this ListView is that it doesn't go back to the first or to the last item after a scroll over the list... It stays on a position where list is not filled.

Anyone got an idea to make it work ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it is a really good idea.
Getting against the OS conventions only confuses the user. On Android, when you are at the end of a list, you get a colored tint letting you know that they are no more items. Changing the color of that tint to fit the theme of your app would probably be a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should override `onOverScrolled`, which is called to say that the list has been over scrolled, and in that function scroll the `ListView` back to the point where you want it using `smoothScrollToPosition`.

It'd look something like:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    if(scrollY < 0) {
        smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    } else if(scrollY > MAX_SCROLL) {
        smoothScrollToPosition(getAdapter().getCount());
    }
}
```

MAX_SCROLL will have to be determined by you using the height of your list items and the number of items in your adapter although it looks like you've already figured that out in your question so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: overScrollBy and onOverScrolled doesnt trigger on 2.3 )=