# Android ListView scroll to the middle of the view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, xamarin

I have this problem with Android ListView. My View consists of ListView and two floating buttons on the bottom of it. These two floating buttons overlays the last item of the ListView. On the iOS side by default you can drag last ListView's item to the middle of the View and in this way it's possible to see what item it is. When you release the last item it scrolls back to the bottom of the page. On the Android part by default the last item of ListView doesn't drag to the top so that it would create some space after it. Any ideas how it's possible to achieve this kind of behaviour?

Comment: listView.addFooter(View);

Comment: Android does not have the possibility (natively) to bounce-back, like iOS does. Thus you would have to either manually add more space to the View, or use @Budius' method.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the default behaviour you would want on android, however I think it's possible to achieve it using the following method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424780/2350917

I have never tried it though, so tell us how you got on.

Edit:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    if(scrollY < 0) {
        smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    } else if(scrollY > MAX_SCROLL) {
        smoothScrollToPosition(getAdapter().getCount());
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

The best method to solve this and to follow android guidelines, would be to show the floating action buttons when you get to the listview screen and then make them disappear as you scroll down. When you scroll up they would appear again. Like this you could see the content on the last item of the listview.

This method would work if it is not essential to show your floating action buttons ALL the time.

Comment: Yes, probably your second solution would achieve the best result. I think I'll think of that. Thanks!